Python (TKinter + Turtle) - "failed to remove temporary directory"
I'm creating a Python application using pygame, turtle, and tkinter. While everything works fine in my IDE (PyCharm), I encounter an error when trying to restart my program using the onkey event from tkinter in .exe file. The error is:
.exe is created using Pyinstaller: pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=axe.ico main.py
Failed to remove temporary directory: C:/users/lucky/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI135042
Here is my code:
import os
import sys
import tkinter
import turtle
import json
import tempfile
import shutil

os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "True"
import pygame

STANDARD_KEY_BINDING = ["a", "d", "q"]

def cleanup():
    try:
        turtle.bye()
    except turtle.Terminator:
        pass

    pygame.quit()

    temp_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
    try:
        for temp_item in os.listdir(temp_dir):
            temp_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, temp_item)
            if os.path.isdir(temp_path) and "your-app-name" in temp_item:
                shutil.rmtree(temp_path)
                print(f"Removed temporary directory: {temp_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error removing temporary directory: {e}")

def restart_program():
    cleanup()
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)

def game(map_choice):
    # [non-related code]

    background.screen.onkey(fun=player.move_left_swing, key=binds[0])
    background.screen.onkey(fun=player.move_right_swing, key=binds[1])
    background.screen.onkey(fun=restart_program, key=binds[2])

    # [non-related code]

When the function from background.screen.onkey(fun=restart_program, key=binds[2]) is called, There is an "failed to remove temporary directory" error. The application should return to the main window created using tkinter.
What I've Tried:
Verified that the temporary directories are accessible and ensured that pygame.quit() and turtle.bye() are called in the cleanup() function.
Any kind of help on how to fix this error would be appreciated!

What are you trying to achieve? What's the use for combining turtle and pygame?

See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/8701

...turtle, pygame, and Tkinter.

I know it may be very inconvenient to do so, but I don't know pygame at all and I wanted to somehow add background music as well as short, .wav sounds for example when clicking buttons in Tkinter.
